# Recompiling 32 bit C++ library to 64 bit

Tags: c++, recompile

I wanted to use the libtcod library. I'm running windows 8 64 bit and I use dev-c++.

Basically, the tutorial says that "if you are on a 64bit system you'll have to recompile the library, because the pre-compiled are only available for 32 bit systems". How do I do that? It does not explain that so I don't even know what I am supposed to do.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the code and compiling it?

Comment: well in the libtcod folder there is a folder called "src" full of .cpp files, but they are not ALL the files that I need (the library has multiple .h files, while there are only a few .cpp files in there). And I can't compile them/ I wouldn't know how to make them into a .h file.

Comment: http://doryen.eptalys.net/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.2/html2/compile_libtcod_mingw.html Everything is explained here...

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained in the [documentation from the libtcod site](http://doryen.eptalys.net/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.2/html2/compile_libtcod_mingw.html)...

Here is what to do:

In Mingw Shell, type :

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/jice/libtcod
```

Go in libtcod's main directory :

```
cd libtcod
```

And start the compilation :

```
make -f makefiles/makefile-mingw
```

The compilation make take a few seconds depending on your CPU speed. Once it's finished, compile the samples :

```
make -f makefiles/makefile-samples-mingw
```

Check that everything is ok by running the samples :

```
./samples_cpp
```

Comment: Silly me! Thank you very much! I googled it but I didn't find anything! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ouch! it gives me another error. When I compile the "make -f makefiles/makefile-mingw" it says mingw32-gcc not found... What do? Thank you.

Comment: This is certainly because your install is 64b and the makefile is for building à 64b... That's a bit boggus and unprofessional. You can try editing the makefile to replace `CC` and `CPP` by your correct compiler (`gcc` ? `mingw64-gcc` ?) and also the opengl32 lib by an opengl64.